# DSpace XMLUI Batch-Importer: Import fails (No such file or directory)

Tags: dspace

Still failing at trying to batch-import a SimpleArchiveFormat-zip file via the XMLUI. The error message I'm getting is `Import failed
/home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/dublin_core.xml (No such file or directory)`.
This is odd, since creating the directories, creating the mapfile and unzipping the files seems to work all right (see dspace.log and the output from monitoring the "imports"-dir below).

**dspace.log**

```
2016-01-07 14:46:55,800 INFO  org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport @ Created org.dspace.app.batchitemimport.work.dir of: /home/dspace/dspace/imports
2016-01-07 14:46:55,824 INFO  org.dspace.app.xmlui.aspect.administrative.FlowBatchImportUtils @ Attempt UIBatchImport to collection: Fakultätsratsprotokolle der Fakultät für Geisteswissenschaften, zip: import.zip, map: /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip8386418726670935229.map
2016-01-07 14:46:55,825 ERROR org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport @ Unable to create contents directory: /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/
2016-01-07 14:46:55,825 INFO  org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport @ Extracting file: item_001/2011-01-12.pdf
2016-01-07 14:46:55,829 INFO  org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport @ Extracting file: item_001/contents
2016-01-07 14:46:55,829 INFO  org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport @ Extracting file: item_001/dublin_core.xml
2016-01-07 14:46:55,830 INFO  org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport @ Extracting file: item_002/2011-02-09.pdf
2016-01-07 14:46:55,834 INFO  org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport @ Extracting file: item_002/contents
2016-01-07 14:46:55,835 INFO  org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport @ Extracting file: item_002/dublin_core.xml
2016-01-07 14:46:55,835 INFO  org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport @ Extracting file: item_003/2011-04-06.pdf
2016-01-07 14:46:55,836 INFO  org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport @ Extracting file: item_003/contents
2016-01-07 14:46:55,836 INFO  org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport @ Extracting file: item_003/dublin_core.xml
2016-01-07 14:46:55,867 INFO  org.dspace.content.Item @ kai.woerner@uni-hamburg.de:session_id=AF948601DF1A1248669B8BE43058C912:ip_addr=134.100.73.56:update_item:item_id=23
2016-01-07 14:46:55,883 INFO  org.dspace.content.Item @ kai.woerner@uni-hamburg.de:session_id=AF948601DF1A1248669B8BE43058C912:ip_addr=134.100.73.56:create_item:item_id=23
2016-01-07 14:46:55,924 INFO  org.dspace.content.Item @ kai.woerner@uni-hamburg.de:session_id=AF948601DF1A1248669B8BE43058C912:ip_addr=134.100.73.56:update_item:item_id=23
2016-01-07 14:46:55,933 INFO  org.dspace.content.WorkspaceItem @ kai.woerner@uni-hamburg.de:session_id=AF948601DF1A1248669B8BE43058C912:ip_addr=134.100.73.56:create_workspace_item:workspace_item_id=-1item_id=23collection_id=2
2016-01-07 14:46:55,981 ERROR org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport @ AddItems encountered an error, will try to revert. Error: /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/dublin_core.xml  (No such file or directory)
2016-01-07 14:46:55,985 INFO  org.dspace.event.EventManager @ 
2016-01-07 14:46:56,020 INFO  org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport @ Attempted to delete partial (errored) import
2016-01-07 14:46:56,020 ERROR org.dspace.app.xmlui.aspect.administrative.FlowBatchImportUtils @ BatchImportUI - Failure during import: /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/dublin_core.xml  (No such file or directory)
```

**Output from `inotifywait -mr --timefmt '%H:%M' --format '%T %w %e %f' /home/dspace/dspace/imports`**

```
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ CREATE import.zip1190120347740836957.map
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ OPEN import.zip1190120347740836957.map
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE import.zip1190120347740836957.map
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ CREATE,ISDIR import.zip
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ OPEN,ISDIR import.zip
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR import.zip
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ CREATE,ISDIR item_001
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ OPEN,ISDIR item_001
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR item_001
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ CREATE 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ OPEN 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ CREATE contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ OPEN contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ CREATE dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ OPEN dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ MODIFY dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ CREATE,ISDIR item_002
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ OPEN,ISDIR item_002
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR item_002
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ CREATE 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ OPEN 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ CREATE contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ OPEN contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ CREATE dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ OPEN dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ MODIFY dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ CREATE,ISDIR item_003
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ OPEN,ISDIR item_003
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR item_003
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ CREATE 2011-04-06.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ OPEN 2011-04-06.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ MODIFY 2011-04-06.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ MODIFY 2011-04-06.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ MODIFY 2011-04-06.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ MODIFY 2011-04-06.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ MODIFY 2011-04-06.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ MODIFY 2011-04-06.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE 2011-04-06.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ CREATE contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ OPEN contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ MODIFY contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ CREATE dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ OPEN dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ MODIFY dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ MODIFY import.zip1190120347740836957.map
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ OPEN import.zip1190120347740836957.map
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ OPEN,ISDIR import.zip
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ OPEN,ISDIR
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR import.zip
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ OPEN dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ ACCESS dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ OPEN,ISDIR item_001
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ OPEN,ISDIR
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR item_001
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ OPEN contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ ACCESS contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE import.zip1190120347740836957.map
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ OPEN import.zip1190120347740836957.map
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE import.zip1190120347740836957.map
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ OPEN import.zip1190120347740836957.map
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE import.zip1190120347740836957.map
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ OPEN,ISDIR
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ DELETE import.zip1190120347740836957.map
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ OPEN,ISDIR import.zip
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ OPEN,ISDIR
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR import.zip
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ OPEN,ISDIR item_001
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ OPEN,ISDIR
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR item_001
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ DELETE contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ DELETE 2011-01-12.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ DELETE dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_001/ DELETE_SELF
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ DELETE,ISDIR item_001
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ OPEN,ISDIR item_003
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ OPEN,ISDIR
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR item_003
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ DELETE contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ DELETE 2011-04-06.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ DELETE dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_003/ DELETE_SELF
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ DELETE,ISDIR item_003
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ OPEN,ISDIR item_002
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ OPEN,ISDIR
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR item_002
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ DELETE contents
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ DELETE 2011-02-09.pdf
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ DELETE dublin_core.xml
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/item_002/ DELETE_SELF
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ DELETE,ISDIR item_002
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/import.zip/ DELETE_SELF
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ DELETE,ISDIR import.zip
14:36 /home/dspace/dspace/imports/ DELETE_SELF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault: I added the dublin_core.xml to the contents file, [where it does not belong](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Importing+and+Exporting+Items+via+Simple+Archive+Format#ImportingandExportingItemsviaSimpleArchiveFormat-DSpaceSimpleArchiveFormat). I'm sorry.